# Gnuplot invalid x range while plotting temperature over time

Tags: gnuplot

I have a datafile *cpuTemp.txt* in the Format

```
09:16;314
09:19;314
```

and want to plot this using this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set datafile sep ';'                 # seperator ;
set terminal png                     #output format of graph
set term pngcairo size 300,300       #resolution
set output "temp.png"                #name of output file
set title "Temperature over Time"    #title of graph
set xlabel "time"                    #horizontal axis name
set ylabel "celsius * 10"            #vertical axis name
set timefmt "%H:%M"                  #format of time is source file cpuTemp.txt
set yrange [0:600]                   #vertical axis range (optional line)
set xdata time                       #x axis is not numbers, but dates/times
set format x "%H:%M"                 #format of time labels in axis label
set grid xtics lc rgb "#888888" lw 1 lt 0    #grey grid on background
set grid ytics lc rgb "#888888" lw 1 lt 0    #grey grid on background
plot "cpuTemp.txt" u 1:3 title "temperature" w lines lc rgb '#8b1a0e' lt 1 lw 2
```

now when executing i get warnings and this error which i can't figure out:

```
me@box:~ $ ./tempPlotter.sh 
"./tempPlotter.sh", line 15: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

plot "cpuTemp.txt" using 1:3 title "temperature" with lines lc rgb '#8b1a0e' lt 1 lw 2
                                                                                      ^
"./tempPlotter.sh", line 15: x range is invalid
```

- ..why are there no valid points in the datafile?
- ..why is the x range invalid?

Thanks in advance,
Gewure

Comment: Its strange, tha gnuplot complains about invalid xrange, but you access a nonexistent third column in your `plot`.

Comment: where do i access it @Christoph ? Im an absolute noob in gnuplot, sadly.

Comment: In your script you have `plot "cpuTemp.txt" u 1:3`, but you have only two columns. Probably you simply want `plot "cpuTemp.txt" u 1:2`.